# Is it possible to automate Gsutil login?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to automate gsutil based file upload to google cloud store so that the user intervention is not required for login?

My usecase is to have a jenkins job which polls a SCM location for changes to a set of files. If it detects any changes it will upload all files to a specific Google Cloud Store bucket.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Do you have end-users that are running gsutil?

Comment: @jterrace updated for more detail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you configure your credentials once gsutil requires no further intervention. I suspect that you ran `gsutil configure` as user X but Jenkins runs as user Y. As a result, `~jenkins/.boto` does not exist. If you place the .boto file in the right location you should be all set.

Another alternative is to use multiple .boto files and then tell gsutil which one to use with the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable:

```
gsutil config  # complete oauth flow
cp ~/.boto /path/to/existing.boto
# detect that we need to upload
BOTO_CONFIG=/path/to/existing.boto gsutil -m cp files gs://bucket
```

I frequently use this pattern to use gsutil with multiple accounts:

```
gsutil config  # complete oauth flow for user A
mv ~/.boto user-a.boto
gsutil config  # complete oauth flow for user B
mv ~/.boto user-b.boto
BOTO_CONFIG=user-a.boto gsutil cp a-file gs://a-bucket
BOTO_CONFIG=user-b.boto gsutil cp b-file gs//b-bucket
```

Comment: gsutil config is deprecated use gcloud auth login now

Comment: gsutil config is still the correct way to configure standalone gsutil, but gcloud auth login is the correct way to configure gsutil distributed via Google Cloud SDK

Comment: No indication here of gsutil config being deprecated: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config