# Automating gsutil commands

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I'm trying to automate some gsutils commands, but struggling to see where the authentication files are kept and how to re-use (if thats what happens).

I've gone through the gcloud init process in bash...

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
gcloud init
```

All works well when I run

```
  'gsutil ls'
```

Now I'm trying to automate the process, so this would work on a new server adding into a crontab on it (rather than creating a new config each time).

I saw a mention of setting env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, so I copied my credentials from web login to a file and tried it, eg trying as a different user to test

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/user/.gsutil/mycreds
```

and then gsutil ls, but fails.

So I assume I've got the whole credentials thing a bit wrong. I'm assuming there is a file somewhere that was originally created by gcloud which I could use, but I can't see it anywhere ?

I've looked at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509368/is-it-possible-to-automate-gsutil-login) but doesn't seem up to date now, as per last comment.

**Edit**: I have followed Zacharys steps, gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=myfilelocation

However, with 'gsutil ls' I now get..

```
You are attempting to perform an operation that requires a project id, with none configured. Please re-run gsutil config and make sure to follow the instructions for finding and entering your default project id.
```

So my next question would be, where is it looking for the project id ? If I run gsutil config, it seems to create a new set of auth which then creates another error, so have removed that.

Comment: gcloud stores its configuration in ~/.config/gcloud, so if you have a working installation that you set up manually, at the minimum you should be able to copy that configuration to your new server.  There is probably a more elegant way, though.

Comment: Thanks, I can see relevant files there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to do this without diving in too deep to the implementation of authentication for `gsutil`.

If you're using standalone `gsutil` (if you installed via [this method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)), the instructions in the linked question are still valid (as Travis points out).

If you'd like to continue using the `gsutil` supplied via the Cloud SDK, you should use [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Service accounts are the preferred method of authenticating on headless machines or in non-interactive contexts.

Your flow would look something like the following:

1. Create a service account via the [Google Cloud Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
2. On the remote machine, install the Cloud SDK and `gsutil`. If you're not installing interactively, it's better to skip the `curl ... | bash` method. Instead, download [this install archive](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz), extract it, and run the `install.sh` script. This script has options (visible with `--help`); if you specify choices to all of these options, it won't prompt you.
3. Copy the service account to the remote machine. Run `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/service-account.json`.
4. Run `gsutil`. You should be appropriately authenticated.

Comment: You can use service accounts with standalone gsutil, too, and it makes more sense than copying user credentials for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting somewhere, and I can seem to auth, but now its not finding the project id in config, or its inclear where this is set, or how to specificy it ? I have added an edit to the end of the question. Ok, think I'm getting somewhere gcloud config set project 'project-id' seems to be ok

Comment: gcloud config set project 'your project id' should be all you need.

Comment: this probably saved me an hour of parsing through the google api docs - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to set default project and user in `gsutil`. Run the following command:

```
gcloud init
```

Choose `1`. It shows you different users; select the user and then select the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a bucket with project id as name:

```
$ gsutil mb -l eu gs://PROJECT-ID
Creating gs://root****/...
Error: You are attempting to perform an operation that requires a project id, with none configured. Please re-run gsutil config and make sure to follow the instructions for finding and entering your default project id.
```

Steps that resolved for me:

1. `gcloud auth login`
2. `gcloud config set project <PROJECT-ID>`
3. `gsutil mb -l eu gs://<PROJECT-ID>`

```
Creating gs://root***/...
```

The error is gone out of the way and it works as expected.