# I am getting exception while copying file from a Linux machine to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am getting the exception when I am running the below command inside Linux machine.

I am trying to copy one text file from linux machine to Google Cloud Storage bucket.

I have created a service account.

Steps I followed-

1. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/test/shubham_test/xyz.json`
   Here, xyz.json is the key file which was downloaded while creating service account.
2. `gsutil cp test.txt gs://my-bucket/`

I was getting the below exception.

> ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to my-bucket/test.txt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating gsutil commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898687/automating-gsutil-commands)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to advise to use gcloud auth but the answer is already present there ;)

Hope this does the trick: [Automating gsutil commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898687/automating-gsutil-commands)